# LIBXML - how do I get the name of the tag?

Tags: xml, perl, libxml2

I have the following:

```
my $string='<entry><name>Bob</name><zip>90210</zip></entry>';

my $parser=XML::LibXML->new(); 
use HTML::Entities;
my $encodedXml=encode_entities($string,'&\'');

my $doc=$parser->parse_string($encodedXml);

foreach my $text($doc->findnodes("//text()")){
print $text->to_literal,"\n";
}
```

This prints out 'Bob' and '90210';

How do I get the actual node names...I need a way to get all the nodes within my xml tree....ie 'name' and 'zip'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Text nodes don't have names. Perhaps you want the name of the parent?

I think this will work:

```
for my $node ($doc->findnodes('//text()')) {
   print $node->parentNode()->nodeName(), ": ", $node->nodeValue(), "\n";
}
```

I would use

```
for my $node ($doc->findnodes('//*[text()]')) {
   print $node->nodeName(), ": ", $node->textContent(), "\n";
}
```

Note: This later version combines all the text children of the element, so it's not equivalent if a node has more than one text child. They should be equivalent for you, though.

Answer (score 1):

What your code does is select the `text` nodes, which exist as children of the nodes you are looking for.  A text node is a separate entity, and it does not have a name.  You need to navigate to the text node's parent and *that* node will contain the tag name.

Things get trickier with mixed-content nodes that contain both text and element nodes, such as

```
<p>Beginning of <i>sentence</i> and now the end</p>
```

In this case the structure is

```
<p>
 |
 +---text (Beginning of )
 |
 +---<i>
 |    |
 |    +---text (sentence)
 |
 +---text ( and now the end)
```

Comment: "Mixed-content nodes" shouldn't be an issue. Most XML formats don't allow such hierarchies. XHTML is the only of many many I've seen.